# Convergence of quadratically convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of numbers such that $\frac{\vert x_n\vert}{\vert x_{n-1}\vert^2}\leq C$, where $C>0$ is a constant independent of $n$. Is it guaranteed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, if $x_0$ is small enough (for example, $\vert x_0\vert<1$)?

By definition, if $\vert x_{n}\vert\leq C\vert x_{n-1}\vert^2,\;\;(C>0)$, the convergence is quadratic. Also, if $\vert x_{n}\vert\leq C\vert x_{n-1}\vert,\;\;(0<C<1)$, the convergence is linear. So I'm wondering why there is not restriction that $C<1$ for the quadratic convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the hint about the correct answer from Erik Parkinson's answer. The convergence is guaranteed if $\vert x_0\vert C<1$.

Under the above assumption, we can show that the sequence $\{\vert x_n\vert\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a decreasing sequence. Since the sequence is bounded from below by $0$, it converges. The decreasing nature of the sequence can be proved using induction. We have $\vert x_1\vert\leq C\vert x_0\vert^2< \vert x_0\vert$. Then, using the inductive assumption, we have
\begin{equation}
\vert x_{n+1}\vert\leq C\vert x_n\vert^2< \vert x_n\vert C \vert x_{0}\vert< \vert x_n\vert.
\end{equation}
Thus, the sequence converges if $x_0<\frac{1}{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

No. As a simple counter example, let $C = 1$ and $x_n = 1$ for all n.

Update to the answer to reflect the update to the post.

First, I'll assume that all the $x_n$ are non negative, as otherwise all the $x_n$ could just go to $-\infty$ and this would still be satisfied. Given that, this still does not hold, even if $x_0$ is small. This is because if we allow C to be large enough, $x_1$ could still be $1$, along with all the $x_n$ after it. The sequence is only guaranteed to converge to 0 if $C < 1$, or in the case where $x_0 < 1$, if $C < \frac{1}{x_0}$.

From what I know $C < 1$ is part of the definition of quadratic convergence, see for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am free to make an assumption on $x_0$. For example, $x_0 < 1$ or similar. How about the convergence under an extra condition on $x_0$?

Comment: I have modified the question for better clarity!

Comment: @GeethuJoseph Ok, I updated my answer to reflect that, hope it helps!

Comment: Even though Wikipedia says $C<1$, I have seen a lot of articles which do not assume that $C<1$: [Reference 1](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/advstatcomp/rates-of-convergence.html) [Reference 2](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/NM/node3.html) [Reference 3](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mgu/MA128AFall2017/MA128ALectureWeek4.pdf) [Reference 4](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence)

Comment: @GeethuJoseph I see, I think the difference (at least in Reference 1, I haven't looked at the others) is that they are already assuming that the $x_n$ converge to some $x_\infty$. So given that the sequence converges, they just care about how fast it converges.